# Umbraco 7 Multiple Domains and Languages

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have searched but not found a definitive answer so far (honest!).

What I would like to set up is multiple domains, each with 1 or more sites (within a domain, there could be 2 sites, one each for different languages).
eg

**DomainA**

- English site
- French site

**Domain B**

- English Site
- German Site

**Domain C**

- English Site

**Domain D**

- English Site

etc

Ideally :

1. Some content could be shared between sites on either the same or different domains (eg, global page showing links to all the possible sites)
2. Content editors could be defined that could only edit content on their allocated domains (eg an editor could edit Domain A content English or German but not Domain B or Domain C)
3. Visitors could not access pages from another domain 
   eg if there is a page 'NewsList' in Domain B (http://domainb/newlist) they shouldn't be able to view if from Domain D (http://domainc/newslist) from the navigation structure nor by typing in that URL.
4. Some domains may in the future require authentication to visit (not top priority)
5. Need to be able to configure site specific properties (currently doing this by creating a site lookup document type, and using @Umbraco.Content(docid) to look it up and retrieve values)

Can all this be achieved in a single Umbraco instance, or do we need to set up multiple databases and multiple instances (using MSSQL)?

Answer (score 0):

1. it is possible to render content from a global node on other pages
2. it's possible to provide a user with a root node.  This root node can be on every domain.  Eg: domain B (including EN & DE).  But NOT domain C and D (but not A & B).  If you want something more complex, ask on the forums (https://our.umbraco.org/forum/)
3. pages are NOT shared cross parent nodes (being domains and languages)
4. you can protect pages
5. properties are defined on your document types, there is currently no security rules for properties.  They only way to solve this is to create sub document types with the specific properties and to use those document types on the right domain.  You could however enforce this by subscribing to the Save events.